# How to solve PHP Error occurred creating a module symlink in XAMPP server?

Tags: php

I am using script with PHP 8.0 in XAMPP server 8.0.
When creating a module symlink, it says following error:

> Error occured creating a module symlink (...). Please check folder permissions.

Permissions to write in specific folder are allowed.
Can you resolve the error?

Comment: On Windows or a Linux?

Comment: File system permissions are more complex than just a boolean flag. Additionally, Windows symlinks have their own quirks. We really need way more information to diagnose this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is on Windows.